# R: Convert windowed list to 3d array

Tags: r, arrays

I am having trouble with trying to shape my list into a 3d array of (nlength, windows,vars). So my final dimensions required in this case would be dim(14,3,3).
What I need to have is the 3D array format seen when you execute x following the loop as I need this shape for keras AE model (None,3,3).

```
Lat = as.numeric(c('-30.1', '-30.2', '-30.3', '-31.9', '-31.6', '-32.1', '-32.1', '-33.0', '-33.3', '-33.9', '-30.6', '-31.1', '-32.1', '-31.0', '-30.3', "-30.5"))
Lon = as.numeric(c('105.1', '105.2', '105.3', '105.9', '106.6', '107.1', '108.1', '109.0', '109.3', '109.1', '109.2', '109.3', '109.9', '108.6', '108.1', "108.1"))
Speed = as.numeric(c('10.1', '11.2', '12.3', '12.9', '13.6', '15.1', '13.1', '13.0', '12.3','10.1', '11.2', '12.3', '12.9', '13.6', '15.1', '13.1'))
track = data.frame(Lat,Lon,Speed)

window.size = 3
x = list()
x.shape = nrow(track)- window.size+1
for (i in 1:(x.shape)){
  window = track[i: (i+window.size-1),]
  x[[i]] = window
}
```

Executing x; however this is a list, I need list in this format but as **3D array**.

```
[[1]]
    Lat   Lon Speed
1 -30.1 105.1  10.1
2 -30.2 105.2  11.2
3 -30.3 105.3  12.3

[[2]]
    Lat   Lon Speed
2 -30.2 105.2  11.2
3 -30.3 105.3  12.3
4 -31.9 105.9  12.9

[[3]]
    Lat   Lon Speed
3 -30.3 105.3  12.3
4 -31.9 105.9  12.9
5 -31.6 106.6  13.6

[[4]]
    Lat   Lon Speed
4 -31.9 105.9  12.9
5 -31.6 106.6  13.6
6 -32.1 107.1  15.1
...
[[13]]
     Lat   Lon Speed
13 -32.1 109.9  12.9
14 -31.0 108.6  13.6
15 -30.3 108.1  15.1

[[14]]
     Lat   Lon Speed
14 -31.0 108.6  13.6
15 -30.3 108.1  15.1
16 -30.5 108.1  13.1
```

Edited for clarity

Comment: Maybe just use your `dim = c(14,3,3)` to start with and follow through the calc(s) of x.shape to determine where your window+/- is reducing your output to 13L, as it appears going forward you want to calculate this rather than relying on knowing dim beyond [x, 3,3] beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `simplify2array` and `aperm` to make `dim(14,3,3)`.

```
y <- simplify2array(lapply(x, as.matrix))
#y <- sapply(x, as.matrix, simplify="array") #Alternative

y[,,1:2]
#, , 1
#
#    Lat   Lon Speed
#1 -30.1 105.1  10.1
#2 -30.2 105.2  11.2
#3 -30.3 105.3  12.3
#
#, , 2
#
#    Lat   Lon Speed
#1 -30.2 105.2  11.2
#2 -30.3 105.3  12.3
#3 -31.9 105.9  12.9

y <- aperm(y, c(3,1,2))
str(y)
#num [1:14, 1:3, 1:3] -30.1 -30.2 -30.3 -31.9 -31.6 -32.1 -32.1 -33 -33.3 -33.9 ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
#  ..$ : NULL
#  ..$ : chr [1:3] "1" "2" "3"
#  ..$ : chr [1:3] "Lat" "Lon" "Speed"
```

Or based on the approach you have started:

```
y <- array(unlist(x), dim = c(3,3, length(x)))
y[,,1:2]
#, , 1
#
#      [,1]  [,2] [,3]
#[1,] -30.1 105.1 10.1
#[2,] -30.2 105.2 11.2
#[3,] -30.3 105.3 12.3
#
#, , 2
#
#      [,1]  [,2] [,3]
#[1,] -30.2 105.2 11.2
#[2,] -30.3 105.3 12.3
#[3,] -31.9 105.9 12.9
```

Comment: Hi mate, nah has not solved my issues sorry. I need the result as if the x list variable, but i need it that shape but as a 3d array as i need to put in keras model.

Comment: Can you show how your expected result should look like that I can test with `identical`?

Comment: Exactly as seen when calling x, but class is Array not list. I need 14 windows, of a window size being 3 time series long, with 3 features (lat,lon,speed).

Comment: Can you create a dataset (maybe by hand) which I can than use to compare with `identical`?